# iOS Facebook Login Without Opening Browser or native Facebook App

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login

I am using the Facebook Login for my iOS app. However the login flow is not using the native iOS Facebook  integration.

I am using Facebook iOS SDK 3.17 (via pod) and I have followed the setup instructions. The login is working, it is simply not showing the native login dialog. Instead it opens the Facebook iOS app to authenticate...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook changed their login behavior. You can get this to work again by setting the property "loginBehavior" on your FBLoginView to "FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent" in your viewDidLoad method.

```
self.loginView.loginBehavior = FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent;
```

Comment: i agree, in ios8, Facebook has gone back to using the Facebook app as first priority.  can you help explain further how to apply your fix?  i am struggling on where to apply in my app.  thanks!

Comment: Just put this line of code in in your Controllers viewDidLoad method